# Caliburn.micro Mouseclick update TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am still learning Caliburn.micro, so this may be a silly question.
I've got a ListView with a GridView inside of it. I want to be able to click on a row and have it change the text of a TextBlock outside of the ListView.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="titleText" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="4" Text="View a report of all current applications" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" />


    <ListView VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="listView1" SelectedItem="{Binding Key}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CustomListViewItemStyle}" AlternationCount="2" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{StaticResource OrderGroup}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="200"  cal:Message.Attach="[Event MouseLeftButtonUp]=[Action HandleClick($eventArgs)]">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" x:Name="GridView1">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Client Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ClientName}" ></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Application ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" ></GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

As you can see I'm calling the cal:Message.Attach to handle the MountLeftButtonUp event.

This calls the following code:

```
public void HandleClick(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        titleText= "SOME TEST HERE"; 
    }
```

And titleText (the TextBlock I am trying to update) is defined as follows:

```
String _titleText = "";
    public string titleText
    {
        get { return _titleText; }
        set
        {
            if (_titleText != value)
            {
                _titleText = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => _titleText);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this does not update the TextBlock. I step into the code and see that the titleText is changed in the code, but it is not displayed.
I also changed this to just do the same thing on clicking on an image and it worked successfully.

So is there something I may be missing here? Any one with Caliburn.micro experience.

Thanks.

Mudders

Comment: I've not got a lot of experience with Caliburn, but should it be: `NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>titleText)`?  IE.  The property, not the private member?

Comment: Coding Gorilla! Thanks for spotting the obvious! I think I'd been looking at it so long I didn't even notice that anymore! Thanks! My stupidity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was provided by Coding Gorilla - I missed it in the titleText declaration. It should have been calling the property and not the private member - like so:

```
String _titleText = "";
    public string titleText
    {
        get { return _titleText; }
        set
        {
            if (_titleText != value)
            {
                _titleText = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => titleText);
            }
        }
    }
```

Changed that and it worked a treat - so simply a case of me not seeing the problem.
Thanks.